# Javascript: create a copy of an array using slice();

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to create a copy of an array so that I can do modification on one array without affecting the other.

for example:

```
var a = [[1],[2],[3]];
var b = a.slice(0);
b[1].push(100);
b // [[1],[2, 100],[3]];
a // expect: [[1],[2],[3]]; , actual: [[1],[2, 100],[3]];
```

I have also tried:

```
var b = new Array(a);
```

but this puts all [1],[2],[3] to index 0 in the new array.

What am I missing here?

Thanks guys!

Comment: [The `slice()` method returns a **shallow copy** \[...\]](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice).

Comment: use the JSON trick: `b = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(a))` this will do some kind of a "deep copy", then you can modify `b` without messing `a`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you also have to copy the inner arrays:

```
 var b = a.map(sub => sub.slice());
```

Answer (score 0):

`slice()` makes a shallow copy, for **n** levels you could use `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(a))` or recursion:

```js
var a = [[[1]],[2],[3]];

var b = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(a))

b[0][0][0] = 999;

console.log(a)

console.log(b)
```